# How to list upcoming rtcwake jobs

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using rtcwake from util-linux 2.34 on Ubuntu 20.04. When I set my machine to wake up from memory at a certain time, sometimes I'll forget exactly what time that was. Is there a way to display a list of upcoming rtcwake jobs via command line?

Answer (score 2):

use
`sudo rtcwake -m show`
to display a list of upcoming rtcwake jobs.